# Image alignment with a long text in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Can someone help me to achieve this with Flutter:

[image: A long text (retrieved from Firebase) with an image aligned in the top-left corner of it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, please check this package: [Drop Cap Text](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text)

You can use it with an image. I guess this is your case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i want !